# Good and plain code/links for Command pattern applying

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

Can anybody share good and plain code/links for Command pattern applying:

- undo
- queue
- simple method encapsulation

P.S.: Books about patterns I saw.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command